# avro-maven plugin - ClassNotFoundException during induce goal

Tags: java, maven, code-generation, avro

I am using Kafka & Avro in my current project, and I decided to upgrade the way I have been doing things for years.

I always start from an AVDL, as I consider it the cleanest way to describe a schema, then generate Java classes from it using avro-maven-plugin.
When it comes to the AVSC schema files, either I was retrieving them manually from the Java classes, either using exec-maven-plugin to run the command idl2schemata on the Avro tools and generate them.

However, I noticed that avro-maven-plugin released a new induce goal: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2365
This one allowing to generate AVSC / AVPR from java classes directly:

`mvn avro:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=induce`

```
Maven plugin for Avro IDL and Specific API Compilers

avro:induce
  Generate Avro files (.avsc and .avpr) from Java classes or interfaces

  Available parameters:

    allowNull (Default: false)
      Whether to use ReflectData.AllowNull.

    avroOutputDirectory (Default:
    ${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/avro)
      Directory where to output Avro schemas (.avsc) or protocols (.avpr).
      User property: avroOutputDirectory

    encoding (Default: ${project.build.sourceEncoding})
      The output encoding.

    javaSourceDirectories (Default: ${basedir}/src/main/java)
      The Java source directories.
      User property: javaSourceDirectories

    reflectDataImplementation
      Override the default ReflectData implementation with an extension. Must be
      a subclass of ReflectData.
      User property: reflectDataImplementation
```

My goal then became simple, use only avro-maven-plugin to:

1. generate the Java classes from my AVDL file (goal idl-protocol)
2. then generate the AVSC files from my generated Java classes (goal induce)

My pom would be cleaner, and the schema customization done during the idl-protocol would be kept.

So I came with something like this:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                            <goal>induce</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- idl-protocol goal - The source directory of avro files -->
                    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro/</sourceDirectory>
                    <!-- idl-protocol goal - The output directory of Java classes -->
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/avro</outputDirectory>
                    <!-- idl-protocol goal - Customization -->
                    <createSetters>false</createSetters>
                    <stringType>String</stringType>
                    <!-- induce goal - The java source directory -->
                    <javaSourceDirectories>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/avro</javaSourceDirectories>
                    <!-- induce goal - Directory where to output Avro schemas -->
                    <avroOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/avro</avroOutputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

However, using the command `mvn clean avro:idl-protocol avro:induce` on a demo schema:

```
@namespace("com.stack.overflow.kafka.event")
protocol CompensationProtocol {

    record Question {
        int memberId;
        string title;
    }
}
```

always lead to a failure, a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` when executing the induce goal:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.11.1:induce (default-cli) on project compensation: Failed to load class rs.john.doe.git.demo.target.generated-sources.avro.com.stack.overflow.kafka.event.CompensationProtocol -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.11.1:induce (default-cli) on project compensation: Failed to load class rs.john.doe.git.demo.target.generated-sources.avro.com.stack.overflow.kafka.event.CompensationProtocol
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:347)
    ...
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to load class rs.john.doe.git.demo.target.generated-sources.avro.com.stack.overflow.kafka.event.CompensationProtocol
    at org.apache.avro.mojo.InduceMojo.loadClass (InduceMojo.java:184)
    ...
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rs.john.doe.git.demo.target.generated-sources.avro.com.stack.overflow.kafka.event.CompensationProtocol
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:520)
    at org.apache.avro.mojo.InduceMojo.loadClass (InduceMojo.java:182)
    at org.apache.avro.mojo.InduceMojo.induceClasses (InduceMojo.java:124)
    at org.apache.avro.mojo.InduceMojo.induceClasses (InduceMojo.java:115)
    at org.apache.avro.mojo.InduceMojo.induceClasses (InduceMojo.java:115)
    at org.apache.avro.mojo.InduceMojo.induceClasses (InduceMojo.java:115)
    at org.apache.avro.mojo.InduceMojo.induceClasses (InduceMojo.java:115)
    at org.apache.avro.mojo.InduceMojo.induceClasses (InduceMojo.java:115)
    at org.apache.avro.mojo.InduceMojo.execute (InduceMojo.java:103)
    ...
```

The Java classes are properly generated as usual, but not the AVSC files.

I tried to run the induce goal only, to have the classes into a source folder rather than target, I even used public Avro generated avro classes.. the exception was always there.

To figure the root cause of the exception, I even went into the `InduceMojo.class` of the plugin sources, extracted the relevant sources, build a custom project with maven plugin dependencies.. but I couldn't reproduce.

When provided with the proper classname (here `rs.john.doe.git.demo.target.generated-sources.avro.com.stack.overflow.kafka.event.CompensationProtocol`), my own class loader was able to load it rather than throwing an exception:
https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/mojo/InduceMojo.java#L182

At that stage, I have more or less gave up on using the induce goal, but I still have hopes that you guys will have a nice idea to solve this !

Comment: I would not use induce option... As you've explained, the generated classes from the AVSC already have a static SCHEMA$ field with the AVSC string, if you need it at runtime. I've also done the exec plugin trick... Why do you actually need the AVSC files? The schema registry doesn't use them, and neither does Kafka

Comment: I'll also note that Java packages cannot have hyphens. That seems to be part of the issue here. And neither should target be in the package name